# Fundraising Thermometer Approach

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I need to create a thermometer type widget for a website, where I can feed in a goal and current amount, then generate a graphic that shows the progress.  I was thinking something with jQuery/CSS would be the best approach, but then I started thinking maybe just using a vertical slider from the jQuery UI library and skinning it.  How would you all approach this?  I've looked for a plugin but haven't come across anything relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the indicator by a simple div with `background` image, positioned by JS.

1. create a div
2. set the height / width
3. set a bg image
4. calculate the position of the bg image based on the values
5. set the `background-position` css property form the result

Comment: Went ahead with this method and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! It'll be helpful for all of us if you can share your code here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can checkout this widget

http://david.dupplaw.me.uk/developer/jquery-thermometer

Though in the current version if you change the lower value to anything other than zero the UI is not updated perfectly. The corrected version can be found:

https://github.com/mahfuzmohammad/jquery.thermometer